# Cannot gain super user access after rooting

Tags: android

I have installed an android app developed by me on Moto g2. But i want to access a output files generated by running the above app. To do this I have rooted my phone. Now how will access the app's data

```
user$ adb shell
motog$ su
error:permission denied
motog$ sudo su
error: no command sudo
```

I want  to move to /data/data/appname where output file will be found.
P.S I have rooted phone properly.
Thanks

Comment: Likely better for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The phones sometimes have separate settings for _adb root_ and _app root_ (IIRC, root: none/app/adb/both). Dis you check it?

Comment: No, obviously you **have not** rooted the phone in the way you think you have.  But you shouldn't need to root to access data from an app you are developing - if it is a debug app you can use the run-as tool, or you can build in copy-to-External-Storage functionality or even an FTP server into a temporary build signed with your release key.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thks u mean i hv to choose debug app from IDE? build in copy-to-external storage? i dont understand. can u plse explain?

Comment: Your goal of exporting private data from your own app during testing has been covered in numerous other questions here over the years.  Use the search feature.

Answer (score 1):

In case nothing else helps (and the adb root is allowed in settings), you can:

1) set permissions on your app's folder (it worked for me a while ago)

2) copy the files to sd card (I mean, have your app copy the files to the sd card -- you will have to give your app a permission to write to sd card)

BTW, there's no `cp x y` but there is `cat x >y`

In addition, Eclipse has a file explorer: Menu: Window --> Open Perspective... --> DDMS --> choose a device on the left --> File Explorer tab on the right --> see the files on the right.

Whether this tool will help you depends on the device and maybe something else, at the moment I cannot read /data/data.

Comment: Thks. But no use. It is telling permission denied. motog$ cat /data/data/---filename > destfilename

Comment: The proposal is that you have your app do this, since you cannot do it from the adb shell on a secured device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  u mean i will hv to write the code to display image in the activity file?

Comment: You will have to add a button (or menu item, or whatever) and in its _onClick_ handler write the code that copies your files to the sd card (say, _/sdcard/mypath_). Then, you will be able to `adb pull /sdcard/mypath/`